# What's the difference between opening a file with ios::binary or ios::out or both?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to figure out the difference between opening a file like:

```
fstream *fileName*("FILE.dat",ios::binary);
```

or

```
fstream *fileName*("FILE.dat",ios::out);
```

or

```
fstream *fileName*("FILE.dat",ios::binary | ios::out);
```

I found that all of these forms are identical: in all cases, the same output on the file is produced using either `*fileName*<<` or `*fileName*.write()`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`ios::out` opens the file for writing.

`ios::binary` makes sure the data is read or written without translating new line characters to and from `\r\n` on the fly. In other words, exactly what you give the stream is exactly what's written.

Comment: and what does it mean to use both?

Comment: Well, you'd be writing to a file without translating any characters.

Comment: So if I don't mark an ifstream as binary, and read, say 10 doubles from it, and Windows finds a random '\n' in the data, then the stream get expanded from `10*sizeof(double)` to `10*sizeof(double) +1` as a `\r` is inserted, and overwrites then end of my double buffer?

Answer (score 11):

Opening a file with ios::binary controls how newline characters are handled. On Windows, they are expanded to CRLF pairs. That's it - it has no effect on how things like operator<< work.

Comment: CLRF stands for carriage-return, line feed. These are the two bytes used to specify a new line in Windows text encoding. It's mostly redundant because on a computer, you really only need a new-line character.

Comment: Long time ago, in the days of Teletypes and typewriters, output machines had carriages that moved left to write as characters were printed.  One command, `Carriage Return`, moved the carriage back to the left.  Another command, `Linefeed`, advanced the paper to the next line.  These two commands could be executed independently so that the paper advanced mid-line (using `Linefeed`) or rewriting the current line (using `Carriage Return`).  As a pair, they cause the printing to start at the left margin of the next line.

Comment: Unix people, being impatient typists, decided that the computer should handle both `Carriage Returns` and `Linefeeds`, improving productivity by typing less characters.  This new command was called `Newline`.  On some output systems you could see the carriage move left and the paper advance for each `Newline`, including blank lines.  The C language decided to make peace and let the OS provide translations (without `ios::binary`) or provide  no translations (with `ios::binary`).  The `ios::out` determines data direction (*out from the computer*).

Comment: thank u mr. Thomas
so can u give me one difference between using
ios::binary
and
ios::out | ios::binary

for opening a file
r nt they identical?