# What Makes a Binary Stream Special?

Tags: c++, file, text, binary, fstream

`std::fstream` has the option to consider streams as binary, rather than textual.  What's the difference?

As far as I know, it all depends on how the file is opened in other programs.  If I write `A` to a binary stream, it'll just get converted to `01000001` (65, `A`'s ASCII code) - the exact same representation.  That can be read as the letter "A" in text editors, or the binary sequence `01000001` for other programs.

Am I missing something, or does it not make any difference whether a stream is considered binary or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the difference between opening a file with ios::binary or ios::out or both?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225600/whats-the-difference-between-opening-a-file-with-iosbinary-or-iosout-or-both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux/Unix/Android there is no difference.

On a Mac OS/X or later there is no difference, but I ***think*** older Macs might change an '\n' to an '\r' on reading, and the reverse on writing (only for a Text stream).

On Windows, for a text stream some characters get treated specially.  A '\n' character is written as "\r\n", and a "\r\n" pair is read as '\n'.  An '\0x1A' character is treated as "end of file" and terminates reading.

I think Symbian PalmOS/WebOS behave the same as Windows.

A binary stream just writes bytes and won't do any transformation on any platform.

Answer (score 5):

In text streams, newline characters may be translated to and from the `\n` character; with binary streams, this doesn't happen. The reason is that different OS's have different conventions for storing newlines; Unix uses `\n`, Windows `\r\n`, and old-school Macs used `\r`. To a C++ program using text streams, these all appear as `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You got it the other way around, it's text streams that are special, specifically because of the `\n` translation to either `\n` or `\r\n` (or even `\r`..) depending on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The practical difference is the treatment of line-ending sequences on Microsoft operating systems.

Binary streams return the data in the file precisely as it is stored. Text streams normalize line-ending sequences, replacing them with `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you open it as text then the C or C++ runtime will perform newline conversions depending on the host (Windows or linux).