# ifstream extraction operator not working

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to read data from binary file using folloing code:

```
fstream s;
s.open(L"E:\\test_bin.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
int c = 0;
while (!s.eof())
{
    s >> c;
    cout << c;
}
```

c is always 0 (current value of c. If I set c to 1, result is 1). File exists and it has data that is not zeros, so problem is not at file. I can read this file using fread and using s.get(), but why given code not working?

Comment: Place an if(s) after opening the file to detect an error (also `while (!s.eof())` is wrong)

Comment: What do you expect 'c' to contain after reading in from the binary file?  A chunk of bits or a complete number?

Comment: It still read nothing, but as I mentioned file is ok and opens successfully.

Comment: Chunk of bits, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ios::binary` flag doesn't necessarily mean that you read and write binary data.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225612/2372604 .  `ios::binary` means "data is read or written without translating..."

What you probably want to do is use `s.read(...)`.  In your case the stream operator attempt to read a complete integer (something like "1234") rather then X number of bits that will fit into your integer.

For reading 4 bytes, something like the folling might work (untested):

```
int n;
while (s.read((char*) &n, 4) && s.gcount() != 0 ) {}
```

Comment: And I need to read complete 4 bytes. You mean that I cannot use >> to read bytes from file?

Comment: "data is read or written without translating..." is the definition of *binary stream*

Comment: This is of course incorrect.  The loop should be `while ( s.read((char*n)&n, 4) && s.gcount() != 0 ) {}`.  Except that it would still just read raw bytes into the `int`, which is never right.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks, I was a bit too hasty.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No it doesn't.  In particular, it will skip leading white space.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm fairly sure the `>>` overloads for `char` and `unsigned char` are formatted, i.e. a `sentry` object is created, and whitespace is skipped by default etc.

Comment: @user657267 A `sentry` object is always created, even for `s.read`.  The difference is that for `>>` (except if the target is a `streambuf*`), the sentry argument is initialized with the `skipws` flag from `ios_base`; with the non-formatted input, it is initialized with the constant `noskipws`, regardless of the state of the flag in `ios_base`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
int c = 0;
char ch;
int shift = 32;
while ( s.get( ch ) && shift != 0 ) {
    shift -= 8;
    c |= (ch & 0xFF) << shift;
}
if ( shift != 0 ) {
    //  Unexpected end of file...
}
```

This is the (more or less) standard way of reading binary 32 bit 
integers off the network.  (This supposes that native `int` is
32 bits 2's complement, of course.)

Some protocols use different representation of 32 bit ints, and
so will require different code.

As for your original code: the test `s.eof()` is always wrong,
and `>>` is for inputting text; in particular, it will skip
leading whitespace (and binary data may contain codes which
correspond to whitespace).

I might also add that you should ensure that the stream is
imbued with the `"C"` locale, so that no code translation
occurs.

Comment: Wouldn't that read the int in Big Endian format ? @James

Comment: In most network protocols, ints are big endian. It's pretty much a standard. (Rather surprising, in a way, since most of the early protocols were developed on DEC processors, which are little endian.)