# using ofstream writes binary without the ios::binary flag C++

Tags: c++

I have a few `std::vector` of length `N` with `long, string, double` types. I am trying to write it to a plain text file this way:

```
int N = 100;
std::vector<std::string> var1String(N), var2String(N), var3String(N), var4String(N);
std::vector<long> var1Long(N);
std::vector<double> var1Double(N);

...

 std::ofstream f(path2file);
      for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
f << var1String[i] << " " << var2String[i] << " " << var1Long[i] << " " << var3String[i] << " " << var1Double[i] << " " << var4String[i] << std::endl;
}
```

although I am not using the `ios::binary flag` it gets written in binary which I can easily read in linux. However I want to write it into a plain ASCII text file. (Note: I've also tried converting the `var1Long[i]` and `var1Double[i]` to strings without making any difference). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It is part of a larger program that gets some outputs from a server to the vectors in ASCII. As I said, when reading teh binary with linux or running the program using `std::cout` instead `f` it prints just fine. I just do not understand what might be causing the stream to be passed as binary.

Comment: Could you post an example output? (hex, ASCII)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, this just creates a text file? - please post *actual* code to reproduce the problem, this doesn't even compile (varLong1 is not declared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think `ios::binary` does?

As [explained by Nick Bedford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225612/4113344) in «[What's the difference between opening a file with ios::binary or ios::out or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225600)»:

> `ios::binary` makes sure the data is read or written without translating new line characters to and from \r\n on the fly. In other words, exactly what you give the stream is exactly what's written.

It does *not* mark a file for binary content, it just keeps from translating C new line to their textual representation. Its absence does hence *not* prevent a file from containing binary data.

**In short:** you get binary data in your file because your "string" variables do contain binary data.