# CEREAL failing to serialise - failed to read from input stream exception

Tags: cereal

I found a particular 100MB bin file (CarveObj_k5_rgbThreshold10_triangleCameraMatches.bin in minimal example), where cereal fails to load throwing exception "Failed to read 368 bytes from input stream! Read 288"

The respective 900MB XML file (CarveObj_k5_rgbThreshold10_triangleCameraMatches.xml in minimal example), built from the same data, loads normally.

The XML file was produced by

```
    // {
        // std::ofstream outFile(base + "_triangleCameraMatches.xml");
        // cereal::XMLOutputArchive  oarchive(outFile);
        // oarchive(m_triangleCameraMatches);
    // }
```

and the binary version was produced by

```
    // { 
        // std::ofstream outFile(base + "_triangleCameraMatches.bin");
        // cereal::BinaryOutputArchive  oarchive(outFile);
        // oarchive(m_triangleCameraMatches);
    // }
```

Minimal example: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fu9e8km0mwbhxvu/AAAfrbqn_9Tnokj4BVXB8miea?dl=0

Version of Cereal used: 1.3.0

MSVS 2017

Windows 10

Is this a bug? Am I missing something obvious?
Created a bug report  in the meanwhile: https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/607

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular instance, the "failed to read from input stream exception" thrown from line 105 of binary.hpp arises because the `ios::binary` flag is missing from the `ifstream` constructor call. (This is needed, otherwise `ifstream` will attempt to interpret some of the file contents as carriage return and linefeed characters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225600/whats-the-difference-between-opening-a-file-with-iosbinary-or-iosout-or-bot) for more information.)

So the few lines of code in your minimal example that read from the .bin file should look like this:

```
vector<vector<float>> testInBinary;
{
    std::ifstream is("CarveObj_k5_rgbThreshold10_triangleCameraMatches.bin", ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(is);
    iarchive(testInBinary);
}
```

However, even after this is fixed there does also seem to be another problem with the data in that particular .bin file, as when I try to read it I get a different exception thrown, seemingly arising from an incorrectly encoded size value. I don't know if this is an artefact of copying to/from Dropbox though.

There doesn't seem to be a fundamental 100MB limit on Cereal binary files. The following minimal example creates a binary file of around 256MB and reads it back fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/memory.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/xml.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<vector<double>> test;
    test.resize(32768, vector<double>(1024, -1.2345));
    {
        std::ofstream outFile("test.bin");
        cereal::BinaryOutputArchive oarchive(outFile, ios::binary);
        oarchive(test);
    }

    vector<vector<double>> testInBinary;
    {
        std::ifstream is("test.bin", ios::binary);
        cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(is);
        iarchive(testInBinary);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It might be worth noting that in your example code on Dropbox, you're also missing the `ios::binary` flag on the `ofstream` constructor when you're writing the .bin file:

```
/// Produced by:
// { 
    // std::ofstream outFile(base + "_triangleCameraMatches.bin");
    // cereal::BinaryOutputArchive  oarchive(outFile);
    // oarchive(m_triangleCameraMatches);
// }
```

It might be worth trying with the flag set. Hope some of this helps.

Comment: Great success. Txs :). ios::binary indeed